# Is it possible to tell if a function of noop in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to be able to tell if a function is noop. I was looking for a built in method such as angular.isNoop() but couldn't find anything. Is there anything that differentiates a noop?

Comment: well, if you're getting the noop from a shared location, they'd all contain the same function, thus allowing you to do an exactly equals check. Otherwise all you can do is look at the .toString() of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A noop is simply a function that contains no operations. You can test for a specific noop function by using `===`

For example;

```
console.log(x === angular.noop);
```

Will print true if `x` was assign the noop from Angular, but this will not work if `x` is using the noop from jQuery.

To check if a variable looks like a noop. You just need to see if the function string ends with `{}`. You can try something like this.

```
console.log(angular.isFunction(x) && /\{\}$/.test(x.toString()));
```

The above should work even in the code is minified.

Answer (score 2):

A noop function has a name just like any other function. That name is `noop`. So you can check for it just by calling:

```
var theFunction = angular.noop;
theFunction.name === 'noop'
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not a typical task, it is unlikely that the framework will have one.

```
function isNoop(fn) {
  var trimRegex = /^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g;

  try {
    return !fn.toString().match(/{([\s\S]*)}$/)[1].replace(trimRegex, '');
  } catch (e) { };
}
```

It does not check for noop statements within function, of course. The credits for `trimRegex` go to jQuery.

Comment: is this a jQuery feature? Something like `$.isNoop()`?

Comment: @ThinkingMedia Nope. But that's the regex I'm using for trims, it originally belongs to $.trim.